# Multithreading code too slow with many workers but fast with few

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, brute-force

I wrote a code to speed up a brute force algorithm, i decided to use multithreading. Though I'm new to multithreading, and I understand that by creating large pools of workers(threads), and dividing jobs to them, the brute force should be super fast. Well, my code below works faster with few workers(10 or less), but slower with lots of workers(1000). Why the strange behaviour and where is the mistake?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
            List<Callable<Integer>> callList = new ArrayList<>();
            Callable<Integer> worker;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                worker = new WorkerThread(start, end, id);
                Thread.currentThread().setName("Staff  "+i);
                callList.add(worker);
                start = end;
                end = end + addition + 1;
            }
            int result = executor.invokeAny(callList);
            System.out.println("Done Work");

            System.out.println(result);
            executor.shutdownNow();
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Comment: There are probably a lot of overheads in the task scheduler and threads accessing data. You probably want as many workers as logical CPU cores.

Comment: The level of parallelism is limited by the computer's hardware. For instance, if you only have 8 processors then only 8 threads can run at a time (across all processes). Having too many more threads than available processors introduces overhead—especially when the task is CPU-bound.

Comment: @Slaw I'm using mac with only 2 cores and 1 processor (Intel Core i5 2.4 GHz). Those that mean I can only run 1 thread at a time?

Comment: It's possible I'm using the wrong terminology. If your computer has two cores then it should be able to run at least two threads in parallel. For another example, on my Windows 10 machine I have four cores but eight logical processors, which I believe means I can run eight threads in parallel.

Comment: No, 2 cores means that 2 threads can execute in parallel. When they need to do do something what doesn't need the CPU (typically IO), then having more of them is better. Typically, 2 * numberOfCores threads are used. `+++` Concerning hyperthreading, Slaw is right, the virtual cores (logical processors) count, so they really can run 8 threads in parallel. There are cases when not using all virtual cores is better, but they're rare.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Slaw's comment, when you run a process in parallel, there is a limited amount that the processor can actually do in parallel. When using a number of threads less than or equal to the number the computer has, the processor *can* (if not given other tasks) theoretically run the code at the same time. However, above this, and the processor has to start switching back and forth between threads to make it appear as if the program is running in parallel (when in reality, it is running sequentially). This switching between processes takes time (and slows down the program).

> For more on this read about:
>   schedulers and dispatchers